# Insert UTF8 string to MySQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures, utf-8

I keep getting "Incorrect string value" error when trying to insert a string to MySQL.

The column type is "text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci"
I use a stored procedure, called from C# code.

Already tried the following:

- Adding "charset=utf8" to the web.config
- Converting the string to Encoded byte array

Comment: Can you share the c# code that calls the sp? And what does the string look like? Does the code work in a console app? Please note that `utf8` is not a valid encoding. `utf-8` is...

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a stored procedure always explicitly specify a character set for the parameters like this:

create procedure `auth_add_public_user`(p_login varchar(100) **character set    utf8**,...

See [bugreport](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13909) for more detail.